# How to delete a specific object from json array response

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Need to delete a specific object from JSON response based on the object contains a specific element    And then return the new JSON after deleting the object.
Response below :

```
resObj = {
        links: [{
                rel: "self",
                href: "https://porter.revinate.com/hotels/136964/reviews?rating=4,5&feedback=positive&languageSlug=en&reviewSiteSlug=thefork&size=6&sort=dateCollected,desc{&page}"
            },
            {
                rel: "next",
                href: "https://porter.revinate.com/hotels/136964/reviews?rating=4,5&feedback=positive&languageSlug=en&reviewSiteSlug=thefork&page=1&size=6&sort=dateCollected,desc"
            }
        ],
        content: [{
                body: "Best meals in Mackay",
                author: "Jeffery B.",
                dateCollected: 1612469854,
                updatedAt: 1612469854,
                rating: 5,
                reviewSite: {
                    name: "TheFork",
                    mainUrl: "http://www.thefork.com/",
                    slug: "thefork",
                    links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/reviewsites/129"
                    }]
                },
                language: {
                    name: "English",
                    englishName: "English",
                    slug: "en",
                    links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/languages/2"
                    }]
                },
                subratings: {
                    Setting: 5,
                    Service: 5,
                    Food: 5
                },
                links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/reviews/761621699"
                    },
                    {
                        rel: "hotel",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/hotels/136964"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                body: "Food is always delicious, service is always professional. Will return",
                author: "Reet A.",
                dateCollected: 1610482316,
                updatedAt: 1610482316,
                rating: 5,
                reviewSite: {
                    name: "TheFork",
                    mainUrl: "http://www.thefork.com/",
                    slug: "thefork",
                    links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/reviewsites/129"
                    }]
                },
                language: {
                    name: "English",
                    englishName: "English",
                    slug: "en",
                    links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/languages/2"
                    }]
                },
                subratings: {
                    Setting: 5,
                    Service: 5,
                    Food: 5
                },
                links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/reviews/759347119"
                    },
                    {
                        rel: "hotel",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/hotels/136964"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                body: "Pleasant welcome on arrival, good service for food and drinks orders I did wonder about the “frothy” wine! Prompt meal service delivery with good tasting meal. Schnitzel looked a bit dry/ overcooked on arrival but it wasn’t when tasted",
                author: "Carol L.",
                dateCollected: 1610223622,
                updatedAt: 1610223622,
                rating: 4.25,
                reviewSite: {
                    name: "TheFork",
                    mainUrl: "http://www.thefork.com/",
                    slug: "thefork",
                    links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/reviewsites/129"
                    }]
                },
                language: {
                    name: "English",
                    englishName: "English",
                    slug: "en",
                    links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/languages/2"
                    }]
                },
                subratings: {
                    Setting: 4,
                    Service: 5,
                    Food: 4
                },
                links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/reviews/759012094"
                    },
                    {
                        rel: "hotel",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/hotels/136964"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                body: "Very nice meals , only down fall is price of dri ks and no one at bar to serve had to.wait around 10min. No one at door to book us in and check covid shit.",
                author: "Brad V.",
                dateCollected: 1609877414,
                updatedAt: 1609877423,
                rating: 4.5,
                reviewSite: {
                    name: "TheFork",
                    mainUrl: "http://www.thefork.com/",
                    slug: "thefork",
                    links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/reviewsites/129"
                    }]
                },
                language: {
                    name: "English",
                    englishName: "English",
                    slug: "en",
                    links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/languages/2"
                    }]
                },
                subratings: {
                    Setting: 3,
                    Service: 5,
                    Food: 5
                },
                links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/reviews/758491793"
                    },
                    {
                        rel: "hotel",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/hotels/136964"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                body: "Great food, great service",
                author: "Dani-Lee A.",
                dateCollected: 1609877414,
                updatedAt: 1609877423,
                rating: 5,
                reviewSite: {
                    name: "TheFork",
                    mainUrl: "http://www.thefork.com/",
                    slug: "thefork",
                    links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/reviewsites/129"
                    }]
                },
                language: {
                    name: "English",
                    englishName: "English",
                    slug: "en",
                    links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/languages/2"
                    }]
                },
                subratings: {
                    Setting: 5,
                    Service: 5,
                    Food: 5
                },
                response: {
                    body: "Hi Dani-Lee, thanks so much for the review. Hope to see you here again soon! Thanks, Isabel :)"
                },
                links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/reviews/758491794"
                    },
                    {
                        rel: "hotel",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/hotels/136964"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                body: "Friendly staff, great food, large portions. Delicious",
                author: "Vanessa H.",
                dateCollected: 1609877414,
                updatedAt: 1609877423,
                rating: 5,
                reviewSite: {
                    name: "TheFork",
                    mainUrl: "http://www.thefork.com/",
                    slug: "thefork",
                    links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/reviewsites/129"
                    }]
                },
                language: {
                    name: "English",
                    englishName: "English",
                    slug: "en",
                    links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/languages/2"
                    }]
                },
                subratings: {
                    Setting: 5,
                    Service: 5,
                    Food: 5
                },
                links: [{
                        rel: "self",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/reviews/758491795"
                    },
                    {
                        rel: "hotel",
                        href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/hotels/136964"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        page: {
            size: 6,
            totalElements: 79,
            totalPages: 14,
            number: 0
        }
    }
```

I require to delete the review Object which contains href: "https://porter.revinate.com:443/reviews/758491793" since it's a negative review though it has 4.5 stars.

I have tried as below:

```
var objCount = resObj.content.length;
                    for (var x = 0; x <= objCount; x++) {
                        for (var y = 0; y <= 1; y++) {
                            var curentreviewlink = resObj.content[x].links[y].href;
                            // console.log("link value for checks: ", curentreviewlink);
                            arrayRemovalReviews.forEach((reviewlink) => {
                                // console.log(reviewlink);
                                if (reviewlink == curentreviewlink) {
                                    resObj.content.splice(x, 3);
                                    // console.log("After removal one :", resObj);
                                    res.json(resObj);
                                    res.end(resObj);
                                    return;
                                }

                            });
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: May you show an example to illustrate what you want? And perhaps show what you have tried so far, and the problems you ran into.

Comment: add your response to the question